# DateTime comparison, minus certain timeframe? c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Say I have these two DateTime objects:

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(1900,12,1,1,1,1);
var dt2 = new DateTime(1900, 12, 1, 1, 59, 1);
```

Obviously if I do `DateTime.Compare(dt1,dt2)` the method will return a value indicating they do not equal the same (because of the 59/minute component).

If I only want comparison with precision restricted to a certain value (i.e. same day - dont care about hours/minutes etc) is the best way to do this just to rebuild each datetime object?

I.e.

```
DateTime.Compare(new DateTime(dt1.Year,dt1.Month,dt1.Day,1,1,1),new DateTime(dt2.Year,dt2.Month,dt2.Day,1,1,1))
```

or is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Also, 59 hours is not a valid time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a built in function to get the Date from a DateTime, namely the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property:

```
DateTime.Compare(dt1.Date,dt2.Date)
```

In theory you could compare year, month and day in that order instead of building a new DateTime, but since DateTime is a small struct building it is rather cheap, causes no heap allocations etc. And the code is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the same date, just compare the `Date` properties:

```
dt1.Date == dt2.Date
```

If you need down to the same hour, or up to the same month, you need to use the constructors as you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

The same day is easy - just use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property:

```
dt1.Date.CompareTo(dt2.Date)
```

For other granularities you would probably need to manually build different values though.